# What's a good strategy for coming up with a lab name?

Tags: assistant-professor, lab-management

I'm going to be starting a research lab as a junior faculty, what is a good strategy for coming up with a lab name?

How important is a lab name in differentiating yourself in the field or potentially attracting graduate students?

Is it common for one to use their last name, i.e. 'Smith Lab' or should it be a term from the research domain?

Comment: I like "Smith's Research Domain." It imbues some sort of implicit domination. Really though, at my university, individual faculty get "NAME Lab" and groups of faculty get specialty names when working together.

Comment: In some universities (US) you will need to be careful because certain designations must be officially approved at a very high level because the word has some sort of legalese meaning  (i.e., Smith's "Center' for Great stuff needs high level approval, but Smith's Institute (or Lab) for Great Stuff  doesn't need anyones. (Or vice-versa). Seriously, if the lab name is what is keeping you up nights, then I'd worry about you.

Comment: I've always hated the "Smith Lab" naming convention (which Smith? at which university? which years?), but my PhD advisor had a straightforward lab name the "CFD Lab" for Computational Fluid Dynamics Lab, which no one outside our university ever used, and there were lots of similar names within engineering and computing departments for their version of a similar thing (Comp. Fluid Mechanics Lab, Comp. Fluid Phys. Lab, etc., etc.). I don't think the lab name is useful at all for junior faculty unless you're already or nearly a rock star in your field.

Comment: [Obligatory Ph.D. Comic](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1801)

Comment: @Bill Barth, like your last sentence. This is the exact concluding remark in the above discussion.

Comment: You should read funding applications for your preferred agencies.  If you can see a pattern - names like X get funded with higher probability than names like Y - then you will want to choose an X style name.

Comment: Isn't it your middle name plus the street you grew up on?  Or am I confusing genres?

Comment: You should find some megatrends and buzzwords, hand them to a PR consultant and name the lab whatever comes out. It sounds like a joke, but there are (hundreds of) thousands of grant dollars to be had - and some of them are handed out on a "wow that sounds cool basis"...

Answer (score 5):

You should use your own name in the name of your lab because it (likely) has existing name recognition.  You should not include the subject of research in the lab name because it will evolve over time and shut you out of potential collaborations beyond the subject stated in the name.

Comment: I'd never name a lab after myself: traditionally, in my country, if there is a lab named after a person, it's because he or she is dead...

Comment: I second @MassimoOrtolano. It works the same in my (a different) country.

Comment: I think this varies by discipline. I think in biology "Smith lab" is the standard, but in computer science it would border on arrogance and instead the lab is named after the subject of inquiry.